# Using cron to exclude some folders with mtime

Tags: cron

I'm trying to get a report of file changes for development reasons and just want a simple cron command. With some Googling I managed to discover that you can get a list of files based on time-stamp changes emailed to you.

I'm trying to use this:

```
find /home/username/public_html/dev --exclude ".admin/cache/*" --exclude ".cache/*" --exclude ".cache/*"-mtime -1 \! -type d -ls
```

But I get this error:

```
find: unknown predicate `--exclude'
```

Also, is there such a command as include, or something that does the opposite? instead of excluding you're including?

Comment: Also i just discovered that you can create a new cron for different folders. So that kind of answers my include. Would be still good to know how to exclude. Though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--exclude` is not listed in my copy of the `find(1)` man page.  I'd try something like this:

```
find /home/username/public_html/dev -path ".admin/cache" -prune -o -path ".cache" -prune -o -mtime -1 \! -type d -ls
```

Comment: Thanks kevin, just checking now. But i think i have the wrong idea of this. Its seems to send me a report on file changes even when i reload a page? I think i need something else. Something that scan changes only within the file and not the actual time stamp or whatever it does.

Comment: Have you considered placing the files under version control and then running `git status` or `hg status` via cron?  This has the added benefit of keeping a history of these files, though you'll probably have to manage that by hand (but OTOH both git and hg are very scriptable).

Comment: Yes i have looked ta that kevin, and to be honest it tok me a lot of time to set up and muck around with and i just thought it wasnt worth the time for just me to maintain.

Im testing a ftp php script that sends me email with info. Im hoping its clean and just does what i need. Which is to get a running list of file changes. Im not so much worried about what is changed within the file - because i always put comments through it.

Comment: If your server is munging the mtimes, you need to keep track of file changes somehow.  You could cobble something together to hash the files and compare to the last hash, but at that point you're already 9/10ths of the way to full-blown version control (especially once you account for hash collisions).  Why reinvent the wheel?  Your other option is to make the server stop munging the mtimes.  I wouldn't know where to begin looking for that issue, but it might be easier.